# Find all $f:\mathbb{Q^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q^+}$ so that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Q^+}$ : $f(f(x)^2y)=x^3f(xy)$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all $f:\mathbb{Q^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q^+}$ so that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Q^+}$ : $f(f(x)^2y)=x^3f(xy)$

so $f(0)=0$ when $x=y=0$

$f(f(1)^2)=f(1)$ when $x=y=1$

$f(f(x)^2)=x^3f(x)$ when $y=1$ and therefore $f$ is injective so $f(1)=1$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine all functions satisfying $f\left ( f(x)^{2}y \right )=x^{3}f(xy)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395512/determine-all-functions-satisfying-f-left-fx2y-right-x3fxy) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(f(x)%5E2y)%3Dx%5E3f(xy)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f%3A%5Cmathbb%7BQ%5E%2B%7D%5Crightarrow%5Cmathbb%7BQ%5E%2B%7D%24&p=1). There are also quite a few AoPS threads, e.g., [Nepal National Olympiad](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1631690p10245080), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Functional Equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2389531p19607181), [f(f(x)^2*y)=x^3f*(xy)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h418682p2362286), [Functional equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1962999p13583365), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=xy,y=1\Longrightarrow f(f(xy)^2)=x^3y^3f(xy)$

$y=f(y)^2\Longrightarrow f(f(x)^2f(y)^2)=x^3f(xf(y)^2)=x^3y^3f(xy)$ (check the main equation)

so $f(f(x)^2f(y)^2)=f(f(xy)^2)\Longrightarrow f(x)^2f(y)^2=f(xy)^2$ (multiplicative function)

therefore :

$f(x)=0$

$f(x)=1$ (which is **not possible**)

$f(x)=x^a$ if we sub this in the main equation $\Longrightarrow 2a^2 = a+3 \Longrightarrow a=\frac{3}{2}$ or $a=-1$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problems specifies $f:\mathbb{Q^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q^+}$, so only -1 is possible.